# Send userservice request to openfire

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, openfire

I'm using codeigniter and I want to send an add request to openfire, but i don't really understand what I have to do. I'm a beginner, I read this guide [User Service](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html#post-userserviceusers) and i tried to add a new user with curl [Curl lib](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl), but I'm stuck. Openfire is correctly configured because if I make request from browser the add works
This is my code

```
  $this->load->library('curl');
    $username='usertest';
    $password='password';
    $header='Authorization';
    $content='mykey';
    $this->curl->create('http://myserver.net', 9090);
    $this->curl->http_header($header, $content);
    $this->curl->http_header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    $this->curl->post(array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password)); 
    $this->curl->execute();
```

But users are not added

I'm sorry for my bad English

Comment: Take a look at the second part of this : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2--net-8814

Comment: Thank you, with the aid of this guide there are no more errors, but users are not added, I think there are something wrong in the autentication, or in post parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one implementation of user service client (it is based on Curl but not on codeigniter):

```
 $url = "http://localhost:9090/plugins/userService/users";
  $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <user>
     <username>'.$user['username'].'</username>
     <password>'.$user['password'].'</password>
     <name>'.$user['name'].'</name>
     <email>'.$user['email'].'</email>
  </user>';



  //open connection
  $ch = curl_init();


  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'Authorization: secret',
     'Content-Type: application/xml'
  ));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml );
  #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSPOST, count($fields));
  #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);


  //execute post
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  ob_start(); // outer buffer
  #echo "Code: $http_status | Username: {$user['name']}\n";
  ob_end_flush();
  //close connection
  curl_close($ch);

  if ($http_status == 201) {
  return true;
  }
  else return false;
```

You should set the Content Type and and Authorization as array in a header.
And your XML content looks wrong. It is not only username / password in array.